# NullReferenceException on instantiating line calling new

Tags: c#

```
static void Main()
{
    AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
    // more stuff
}
```

The above compiles fine using csc.exe but throws NullReferenceException at runtime:
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AppHelper..ctor()

```
public class AppHelper
{
    private string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();

    public AppHelper()
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Debugger locates connectionString from app.config but running the executable chokes.

Comment: What's the entire class declaration? What's the line number in the stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

You have code in the AppHelper constructor *or its inline field initializers* that uses a `null` reference.

If you run your code in the debugger, where does it break?

Comment: Does not break in the debugger.  Only breaks when I run the executable.  Seems to be a problem with private string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();  It's as if the executable cannot locate the config file.  However, when I compile, I indicate csc /appconfig:app.config.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing anything in the constructor of the AppHelper class?

Comment: Well he seems not by having only TODO comment in there.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. Problem is somewhere else or the code is different.

The only thing I can think of is that you happen to have inline initializers in the class e.g.

```
public class AppHelper
{

   string something = null;
   int somethingLength = something.Length;

   public AppHelper()
   {
      // TODO
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to copy app.config to ${exeName}.exe.config.  This is how I solved the issue at the end.